# Me podrian ayudar a resolver este problema

Tags: ubuntu

```
fifas@fifas-Lenovo-FLEX-3-1130:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt --fix-broken install» para corregirlo.
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 adwaita-icon-theme : Depende: gtk-update-icon-cache
 libgtk-3-bin : Depende: gtk-update-icon-cache
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt --fix-broken install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado ejecutar `apt --fix-broken install` ?

Comment: si ya lo intente, pero sigue el error mira me manda esto Eliminando `desviación de /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches a /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2 por libgtk-3-bin'
dpkg-divert: error: renombrar obliga a sobreescribir `/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches' con
  un fichero distinto `/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2', no está permitido.